# I want to estimate the mean of a variable. I would like to reduce the SE by controlling for the noise introduced by another second variable

Tags: regression, mean, standard-error

I have a data set with two variables, V1 and V2. V1 is a continuous variable, whereas V2 is a binary variable.

I would like to estimate the mean of V1. V2 is known to be adding error to V1 (V2 being there skews the data left, whereas it being absent skews the data right, both to the same degree). I would like to estimate the mean of V1 while controlling for the error added in to V1 (thereby reducing the SE of the estimate).

One thought I had was to run a regression of V2 predicting V1. I set the two values of V1 to -.5 and .5. It appears to me that the estimate of the constant now predicts the mean, while controlling for the shift added by V2, but also taking in to account the degrees of freedom added by including V2 as a predictor.

Any suggestions about how you would approach this problem are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control for variables in a t-test.

You could run two one sample t-tests, one where V2 = 0 and one where V2 = 1.

The concept of controlling for variables is typical of regreesion; you could do regression with V2 as an independent variable and V1 as the dependent variable and see how far the intercept is from 0, but this would only estimate it for V2 = 0. You'd have to also estimate it for V2 = 1. The two t-test idea seems simpler, unless you are interested in whether V2 has a large and/or significant effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I were to run the two T tests how do I combine them in to a joint assessment though? For example, lets say V2=0 has a mean of -300 and V2=1 has a mean of 700. So doing the two t-tests would yield two different results (one significantly positive the other negative), yet the true result is a mean of 200.

Comment: If you call 200 as the correct value, this explicitly means that you don't want to control for V2.

Comment: Another approach (not really recommended) might be to calculate a regression with the 'control' variables and then do a t-test on the residuals.  Yet another would be calculate your two t-tests and get your measures of effect size from each t-test then calculate the average effect size (assuming equal sample sizes for both values of V2) and throw a confidence interval around that.

Comment: So in my example the two means were -300 and +700. I am thinking that one solution would be to find the average distance from the overall mean for each of the groups and subtract that. So the overall mean is 200, so we add 500 from all the values of V1 where V2=0 and subtract 500 from all the values of V1 where V2=1. In that way I remove the variance on V1 attributable to V2. How does that sound?

Comment: You run two t-tests and you don't combine them. You have two questions. You get two answers. There is not one "true result" there are two.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the follow up. I think I am probably not asking this the right way., which I apologize for. I want to estimate the mean of V1. Some of the variance in V1 is noise, which is due to V2. V2 is therefore increasing the SE estimate around the mean of V1. However, knowing that V2 is adding noise to V1, my thinking is that I should be able to eliminate the variance in V1 due to V2, to get a more precise estimate of V1 (lower SEs). My real question is "What is the mean of V1?" but I think I can use V2 to eliminate the noise it creates to drive down the SE.

Comment: The mean of V1 is the mean of V1. V2 has nothing to do with that. You can't use V2 to lower the standard error and not use it to change the mean that it is the standard error of.

Comment: We agree on what the mean of V1. Imagine that V1 is sampled from a distribution with mean 0 and SD 1. However, before you get the data either 1 is added or subtracted from V1. Thankfully, you know if 1 was added or subtracted from the data (coded as V2). You could do better than estimate your SE based on the raw data, you could adjust it for the effect of V2 by adding or subtracting 1, which would lower your SE. I am trying to do something similar, where I know V2 is doing something like that, but I don't know what value it is adding/subtracting. I tried to clear up my question up top.

Comment: No. That is just not right. It is one thing if you know that 1 is always added or subtracted. But here you don't know what is added or subtracted. You cannot do what you propose.

Comment: I think you are right that what I said reduces it too far. Because any random splitting and centering of the data would reduce the SE to some degree. However, a random splitting would not reduce it as much as a split based on something actually contributing noise, so there should be a way to adjust for what you would expect from a random split while still improving the SE.

Comment: This is just not a fruitful way to go. It doesn't work. If you want to continue, we should move to chat, but there isn't much point.

Comment: Assuming equal size of the two subsets, I think I did it. Setting V2 to .5 and -.5 (instead of 1 and 0), and setting up a regression predicting V1 from V2, the constant now estimates the mean, controlling while removing the variance attributable to V2.

Comment: STOP. please stop.